# AngularJS - How can I $watch a deeply nested array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have data that looks like the following:

```
$scope.boardLists = [{
cards: [{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:2}]
},

{
cards: [{a:3, b:3}, {a:4, b:4}]
},

{
cards: [{a:5, b:5}, {a:6, b:6}]
}];
```

How can I watch for changes in the cards array?

I have tried the following so far:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('boardLists', function(newVal, oldVal){
console.log(newVal);
console.log(oldVal);
});

$scope.$watch('boardLists', function(newVal, oldVal){
console.log(newVal);
console.log(oldVal);
}, true);
```

Comment: option 2 will work

Answer (score 2):

### Scope `$watch` Depths

[image]

```
$scope.$watch('boardLists', function(newVal, oldVal){
  console.log(newVal);
  console.log(oldVal);
}, true);
```

Use `$scope.$watch('item',fn,true);` for a deep watch.

For information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - `$scope` Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths).

Answer (score 0):

$watch is a bit expensive, you can try to use $apply

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  // do something with the scope
  $scope.boardList.push({cards:...});
});
```

$apply will automatically rerun your templates

Comment: I wonder you gave you +1, this "answer" is so unrelated, so random. Funny though.

Comment: this is charme, bro :)